# Is there a way to perform multiple checks on columns using numpy's array indexing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D array of data, and I'm trying to efficiently trim bad columns from this data.  I'm trying to remove any columns that contain the value 0, that have an absolute difference greater than 12 between the minimum and maximum values, or that contain a value greater than 9.5.

The code that I have works, but it's rather slow.  From what I understand, in the background there is a loop over my array for each of these lines of code.  I'm wondering if there is a way to reduce that to one loop.

```
import numpy as np

data_array = data_array[:,abs(data_array).min(0)!=0]
data_array = data_array[:,abs(data_array.min(0)-data_array.max(0)) < 12]
data_array = data_array[:,abs(data_array).max(0) < 9.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to perform those three checks in a single loop.

You are likely to improve performance by properly ordering the trimming operations. Indeed, you should check the condition that removes the most columns first, so that the array passed to the second filter is as small as possible. The same criterion applies to the rest of the filters.

As per the comments your data ranges from `-30` to `30`. One could expect that the most frequent invalid columns are those that include values greater than `9.5`. I'm also guessing that the least frequent reason why columns are discarded is the presence of a zero value. If these assumptions are not correct, you should change the order of the filters accordingly. Further improvement could be achieved by removing unnecessary function calls (such as `abs`).

The following functions implement the same filtering operations in a different order as described above:

```
import numpy as np

def trim(x, low=0, high=9.5, diff=12):
    x = x[:, np.all(x != 0, axis=0)]
    x = x[:, np.ptp(x, axis=0) <= diff]
    x = x[:, np.all(x <= high, axis=0)]
    return x

def trim_reordered(x, low=0, high=9.5, diff=12):
    x = x[:, np.all(x <= high, axis=0)]
    x = x[:, np.ptp(x, axis=0) <= diff]
    x = x[:, np.all(x != 0, axis=0)]
    return x
```

#### Demo

```
In [205]: np.random.seed(213)

In [206]: small_arr = np.random.randint(low=-30, high=30, size=(3, 10))

In [207]: small_arr
Out[207]: 
array([[ 13,   6,   2, -29,  13,  11, -12, -24,   5,   9],
       [ 29,  24,  16, -21, -27,  -5,  -5, -16,  21, -29],
       [-10,  10, -24, -10,   4,   0,  -8, -23,   0,   4]])

In [208]: trim(small_arr)
Out[208]: 
array([[-12, -24],
       [ -5, -16],
       [ -8, -23]])

In [209]: large_arr = np.random.randint(low=-30, high=30, size=(10, 10**6))

In [210]: %timeit trim(large_arr)
77.3 ms ± 470 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [211]: %timeit trim_reordered(large_arr)
16.1 ms ± 174 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [212]: np.all(trim(large_arr) == trim_reordered(large_arr))
Out[212]: True
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer.  I tried implementing this solution, but it didn't speed up my code.  When I posed the question, I didn't mean that I have a loop somewhere else in my code.  Those 3 lines are all I'm using to trim down my array.

Comment: I'm afraid I've misread your question. Can your array have negative values?

Comment: Yes, it can have negative values.  It won't ever have any values greater than 30 or less than -30, though.

Comment: What size is your array?

Comment: It varies.  The arrays are data from experiments.  The sizes range from 500 x 200 to 2000 x 1000.